# C preprocessor metaprogramming: replace macro not in argument list

Tags: c-preprocessor, metaprogramming, preprocessor-meta-program

This question concerns "C preprocessor metaprogramming", i.e. stuff such as [this](http://saadahmad.ca/cc-preprocessor-metaprogramming-2/), [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), [this](https://github.com/rofl0r/order-pp), [this](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms), etc.

I'm writing a non-trivial C preprocessor metaprogram, which in particular needs to "call" macros recursively (using the standard `DEFER`/`EVAL` tricks), and these macros will need to declare variables:

```
#define F(x, y)        \
do {                   \
    int var;           \
                       \
    /* ... */          \
                       \
    DEFER(F)()(var, y) \
} while (0)
```

However, this creates a variable `var` shadowing those on the outer scopes, which is a problem if I need to pass `var` itself as one of the parameters to `F()` (i.e. the recursive "call" needed to access var in the preceding scope). The solution I found was to concatenate a symbol such as `_` at each level of recursion:

```
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_IMPL(x, y)
#define CAT_IMPL(x, y) x##y

#define F(x, y, l)                               \
do {                                             \
    int CAT(var, l);                             \
                                                 \
    /* Code that uses CAT(var, l) extensively */ \
                                                 \
    DEFER(F)()(CAT(var, l), y, CAT(l, _));       \
} while (0)
```

So, assuming the initial "call" to `F()` is of the form `F(x, y, _)`, then `var_` will be declared; in the first recursion level, `var__` will be declared; in the second, `var___`, and so on.

This is working, but the code is littered with occurrences of `CAT(var, l)` making it even more unreadable than such code usually already is. I'm looking for the most compact syntax possible to make the code a little less unreadable, i.e. something like `V(var)`, without needing to spell out the `, l` part explicitly.

However, I'm having trouble writing a macro to make this work (assuming it is even possible).

Here is an MRE, which isn't even a valid C program, but will demonstrate what I'm looking for if run through the preprocessor alone, i.e. using `gcc -E`:

```
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_IMPL(x, y)
#define CAT_IMPL(x, y) x##y

#define F1(x, l) CAT(x, l)

#define CATL(x) CAT(x, l)

#define F2(x, l) CATL(x)

F1(var, _)
F2(var, _)
```

The result of preprocessing this (removing garbage at the beginning) is:

```
var_
varl
```

What I'd like is a version of `CATL()` with a single macro parameter (i.e. without explicitly passing `l` as a parameter) but that still "captured" `l`, so as to get the following output instead:

```
var_
var_
```

Comment: I am tempted to just write an answer: that is not possible, there is no "global stack" in preprocessor, and there is no state, the only stack is the callstack. I do not see a way of capturing the current depth of callstack except for passing a parameter.

Comment: Why don't you pass around `val__...`  in `l` instead of `__...`. If you do that instead, then you can use `l` directly.

You could concatenate with `__COUNTER__` instead of `CAT(l,_)`, but it's an extension.

Comment: @camel-cdr that'd work in the example I gave, but in my actual code `var` is an array and for some calls I pass e.g. `var + index`, plus I have more than one variable. But yeah, a possible solution would be to add these variable names as extra parameters to the macros. Lacking any other "better" solutions, perhaps that's what I'll go with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, there is no "global stack" in preprocessor, and there is no state, the only stack is in the arguments. I do not see a way of capturing the current depth of the callstack except for passing a parameter.

Consider using a different programming language for C code generation - M4, Jinja2, PHP, Python, shell.